# Why does my SwiftUI view lag behind the stepper value when recalculating an array?

Tags: swift, swiftui

Trying to recalculate values inside an array after value of stepper changes but the value updated in the view, lags 1 behind the stepper value.

I have the folling stepper in my SwiftUI view:

```
@StateObject var vm = RecipeViewModel()
@State private var serves = 0

Stepper("", value: $serves, in: 1...20)
    .onChange(of: self.serves) { newValue in
       vm.recalcQuantity(serves: newValue, servesOrig: recipe.servesOrig)
    }
```

And then the following function in my MVVM:

```
class RecipeViewModel: ObservableObject {

@Published var ingredients: [IngredientClass] = []
    
func recalcQuantity(serves: Int, servesOrig: Int) {
   ingredients.indices.forEach {
      ingredients[$0].quantity = ((ingredients[$0].originalQuantity ?? 1.0) / Double(servesOrig)) * Double(serves)
 }
}
```

The ingredient class:

```
class IngredientClass: Codable, Identifiable {
    var id: Int?
    var version: Int?
    var familyId: Int
    var recipeId: Int?
    var indexOrder: Int?
    var quantity: Double
    var originalQuantity: Double?
    var unit: String?
    var name: String
    var updated: String?
    var deleted: Bool
```

The ingredients array is set using onAppear:

```
.onAppear {
   serves = recipe.servesInt
   var ingrArr: [IngredientClass] = []
   recipe.ingredients.forEach { ingr in
     ingrArr.append(IngredientClass(id: ingr.id, version:      ingr.version, familyId: ingr.familyId, recipeId: ingr.recipeId, indexOrder: ingr.indexOrder, quantity: ingr.quantity, quantityOrig: ingr.quantity, unit: ingr.unit, name: ingr.name, updated: ingr.updated, deleted: ingr.deleted))
   }
   vm.ingredients = ingrArr
}
```

recipe in declared like this in the view: var recipe: Recipe, so it is inserted as a paramter from the parent view.
And the reason I create a new array for ingredients, is so that any changes done in the child view, is lost when moving back to the parent.

This kind of works but the calculated value shown in the view, lags 1 behind. I.e. when I press + on the stepper, serves increases by 1 but nothing in the view updates. When I press + again, the view is updated but shows the results for the calculation after the first press. And this conintues, with the view showing the result from the previous press on the stepper instead of the curren value.

What am I missing here?

Comment: You haven't provided enough information but if `IngredientClass` is truly a `class` that I the reason why, `@Published` only emits when the "value" changes. Changing the variable in a `class` does not change "value"

Comment: Show the code you use to declare your view model `vm`, and how you have it (pass it) in your `View` with the `Stepper`. In addition show how you declare `IngredientClass`.

Comment: As hinted by commenters above, based on your code, your view is not looking for updates to the `ingredients` array. As to why it lags, here's a possible timeline: 1. You change the stepper value; 2. This triggers the view redraw; 3. This triggers ingredients update. As a result, although ingredients are updated, the view redraw is not triggered, hence this update is not reflected in the view. Next time you change the stepper value, in the view reflects the result of the previous update.

Comment: In short, subscribe the view to the model update with something like `@StateObject private var vm = MyViewModel()`. As commenters above mentioned, the part where `vm` is initialized is missing from the code so we have to guess what happens there :)

Comment: Tried to edit with more codes, hopefullt more clear now?

Comment: try changing your `class IngredientClass` to `struct IngredientClass`

Comment: Switching from class to struct solved it...  Thx.. :)
Guess there is something I have missed here. I am an experienced developer but a swift/swiftui newbie.